# Regex match tabs that are not at the start of the line

Tags: regex, tabs

So if I have lines like this in a code file and want to do find+replace to get rid of the unwanted tabs.

```
____variable.Property************=****'String Value';
```

The UNDERSCORES are tabs of any number that I DO NOT want to match and the ASTERISKS are tabs on any number that I DO want to match, and return consecutive tabs as one match.

Regex plz.

Comment: Match the tabs at the start, but do not process them, capture the other tabs (that are not at the start) and manipulate them as you need.

Comment: Please provide some code that does not work for you, otherwise, it is not clear how we can help you.

Comment: Regex, not code.

Comment: Is using PCRE then use: [`^\t*\S+\K\t+`](https://regex101.com/r/2mmtgL/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple match (groups) of following tabs (since @anubhava proposal seems not to match several groups as asked), my proposal works with php or python:
[(?<=[^\t\n])(\t+)(?=[^\t])](https://regex101.com/r/jfhY7W/2)

If you neither want to match tabs at end of line just use
[(?<=[^\t\n])(\t+)(?=[^\t\n])](https://regex101.com/r/jfhY7W/4)

This matches groups of tabs sourrounded by non-tab charaters (i.e. not at the begining nor at the end of string)

Comment: Nice try, still matches tabs at the start on a line

Comment: sure? maybe your example is not representative, or I didn't understand your question. Did you check the link? https://regex101.com/r/jfhY7W/1